# Bald men and kippot

Tags: medicine, hair, kippa-yarmulka

How do bald men keep kippah srugas from falling off? (not l'maaseh yet, b"h)

I got a short haircut and am having serious issues, especially in the wind!

Comment: If this is a practical question, please CYLOR :)

Comment: Kippot Serugot.

Comment: @DoubleAA if and when _kipa s'ruga_ gets adopted into English as a word (and if it's spelled _kippah sruga_), its plural may well be _kippah srugas_. (I agree with you that that hasn't happened yet.)

Comment: Double sided sticky tape :)

Comment: @msh210 medicine??

Comment: @CharlesKoppelman, baldness is a medical/genetic condition.

Comment: @Ariel, or a thumb-tack.

Comment: @msh210 so is your answer "Rogaine"? :)

Answer (score 4):

Here is Israel, I've seen two customs (If any are also using tape I wouldn't know):

1. Wear an extra large kippa. Perhaps it is an overcompensating aesthetic, but I have noticed  many bald men wearing kippot that cover their whole heads (and even go into their foreheads). These often keep a snug fit.
2. Wear a [Buchari kippa](http://www.large-kippah.com/kippot/buchari-kippah.htm). Seruga means knitted, so yes, this counts.